# Which transaction manager will be used in the WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions, wcf-binding

I am going through the transactions exist in wcf service but seeking some more clarification on this. I am not sure about which transaction manager wcf will use fo r following scnarios

1) If the wcf service is performing insert in table of one sql server database and delete from table of another sql server database(In same or different server)

2) If the same wcf service is performing insert in table of one sql server database and delete from table oracle database.

3) If wcf service calling 2 different wcf service performing operation on same sql server base database.

Kindly help me providing some understanding on this situations

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following tutorials:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570915/TutorialplusonplusUnderstandingplusTransactionsplu

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38793/Steps-to-Enable-Transactions-in-WCF

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what I want to know is in which scenario it will use LTM, KTM and DTC